# installing expect for bash

Tags: installation, expect

I have downloaded expect (from http://www.tucows.com/preview/8223/Expect) and am having troubles installing it. I generally have troubles installing programs so a very simply explanation would be apreciated. I am a mac user incase that is of importance. Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Package installation methods are OS-dependent.

Comment: OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4

Comment: also I have brew if that helps. I know it can be used to install things but I'm not too familiar with it

Answer (score 9):

For anyone stumbling upon this.

You can also simply install expect with [homebrew.sh](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install expect
```

(http://braumeister.org/repos/Homebrew/homebrew-core/formula/expect)

Disclaimer: I am actually not a mac user.

Answer (score 2):

Installation steps are explained at http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/expect.html

## To Install Expect

1) Download Expect (http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/expect/expect5.45.tar.gz)

2) Untar the package

```
tar -xvf expect5.45.tar.gz
```

3) Login as root and Install Expect by running the following commands inside expect5.45:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr           \
            --with-tcl=/usr/lib     \
            --enable-shared         \
            --mandir=/usr/share/man \
            --with-tclinclude=/usr/include &&
make

make install &&
ln -svf expect5.45/libexpect5.45.so /usr/lib
```

## To Install TCL

1) Download Expect (http://downloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8.6.5-src.tar.gz)

2) Untar thhe package

```
tar -xf ../tcl8.6.5-html.tar.gz --strip-components=1
```

3) Install Tcl by running the following commands:

```
export SRCDIR=`pwd` &&

cd unix &&

./configure --prefix=/usr           \
            --mandir=/usr/share/man \
            $([ $(uname -m) = x86_64 ] && echo --enable-64bit) &&
make &&

sed -e "s#$SRCDIR/unix#/usr/lib#" \
    -e "s#$SRCDIR#/usr/include#"  \
    -i tclConfig.sh               &&

sed -e "s#$SRCDIR/unix/pkgs/tdbc1.0.4#/usr/lib/tdbc1.0.4#" \
    -e "s#$SRCDIR/pkgs/tdbc1.0.4/generic#/usr/include#"    \
    -e "s#$SRCDIR/pkgs/tdbc1.0.4/library#/usr/lib/tcl8.6#" \
    -e "s#$SRCDIR/pkgs/tdbc1.0.4#/usr/include#"            \
    -i pkgs/tdbc1.0.4/tdbcConfig.sh                        &&

sed -e "s#$SRCDIR/unix/pkgs/itcl4.0.4#/usr/lib/itcl4.0.4#" \
    -e "s#$SRCDIR/pkgs/itcl4.0.4/generic#/usr/include#"    \
    -e "s#$SRCDIR/pkgs/itcl4.0.4#/usr/include#"            \
    -i pkgs/itcl4.0.4/itclConfig.sh                        &&

unset SRCDIR
```

4) Login as root and execute the following.

```
make install &&
make install-private-headers &&
ln -v -sf tclsh8.6 /usr/bin/tclsh &&
chmod -v 755 /usr/lib/libtcl8.6.so
```

Comment: I tried step 3 but got this error: zsh: no such file or directory: ./configure

Comment: also, what is TCL, do I really need it and why?

Comment: Tcl package contains the Tool Command Language and is one of the dependencies for Expect. So you need to install it before installing Expect.

Comment: Could I have some help with the ./configure problem?

Comment: Are you logged in as root and inside the extracted expect5.45 folder?

Comment: I am logged in as root (I followed this to do so https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTtVhAEAs2Q)  and I am in expect5.45 but I got this error this time: checking for Tcl configuration... configure: error: /usr/lib directory doesn't contain tclConfig.sh

Comment: I tried installing TCL first and Succeeded and tried to download expect again but got this error: checking for Tcl configuration... configure: error: /usr/lib directory doesn't contain tclConfig.sh

Comment: If TCL is installed properly, tclConfig.sh should be present in usr/lib.